# Cant draw string on jframe

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a window(JFrame) and draw a string on it.However, when i run my code the window appears but without the string i want to draw on it. I have made two classes LabelFrame  and WebStalker.
Here is my code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;

public class LabelFrame extends JFrame {
    private final JTextField urlString;
    private final JButton backButton;
    private final JButton loadButton;
    private Stack urlStack = new Stack();
    String content;

    class GraphicPane extends JComponent {
        public GraphicPane() {
            super();
        }
    @Override 
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.ITALIC, 14));
        g.drawString("Hello, World!", 30, 20);
     }
 }

public LabelFrame() {
    setTitle("WebStalker");
    setSize(600, 600);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    urlString = new JTextField(30);
    backButton = new JButton("Load");
    loadButton = new JButton("Back");
    GraphicPane gp = new GraphicPane();

    this.add(new JLabel("URL"));
    this.add(urlString);
    this.add(loadButton);
    this.add(backButton);
    this.add(gp);

    TextFieldHandler tHandler = new TextFieldHandler();
    ButtonHandler bHandler = new ButtonHandler();

    urlString.addActionListener(tHandler);
    backButton.addActionListener(bHandler);
    loadButton.addActionListener(bHandler);
 }

private class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener {
    @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
         content = URLReaderFinal.Reading(event.getActionCommand());
     }
  }

 private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
         if (event.getSource() == loadButton) {
             try {
                 //remember url for back button
                 urlStack.push(urlString.getText());
                 content = URLReaderFinal.Reading(urlString.getText());
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 System.out.println("Unable to load page");
             }
         } else if (event.getSource() == backButton) {
             if (urlStack.size() <= 1) {
                 return;
             }
             try {
                 urlStack.pop();
                 String urlString = (String)urlStack.peek();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 System.out.println("Unable to load page");
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

}

And the other class :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WebStalker extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LabelFrame frame = new LabelFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: First you do not need to explicitly call the super-constructor in GraphicPane, next you shouldn't really be overriding a JFrame's paint method, it is better to add a JPanel to a frame and draw inside the JPanel's "painComponent" method, and you are also not calling "super.paint(g)" inside the overridden paint method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You panel is using a FlowLayout. A FlowLayout respects the preferred size of a component. The preferred size of your custom component is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

Override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return a proper size for your component.

Also, custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method.

Since you are extending JComponent you should also do a `fillRect(...)` on the entire size of the component to make sure the background is cleared. It would be easier to extend JPanel, then you can just invoke super.paintComponent() at the start to clear the background.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working example and more information on both of these suggestions.